# Performance Increasment and testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, performance-testing

I have this code written and I wanted to get a better performance out of it. Could somebody help me please? If possible I would like my code to get a better performance when rolling high numbers and when it getting to the percentage operation.

```
#implementation of multiple dice rolls at the same time and showing what each dice rolled individually
import random
from collections import Counter

#Welcoming the user to the game
print("Hello and welcome to the dice roller!")
name = input("What is your name?: ")
print ("Hi", name)

while True:
   #Asking the user if he wants to play to make it break the loop and say bye whenever he stops playing
   wants_to_play = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ").lower()
   
   #if statement to determine the number of dice faces, and to "roll the dice" hypothetically.
   if wants_to_play == "y":
      dice_face = int(input("Select the number of faces you want your dice to have. WARNING: if you don't select a whole number, the dice roller won't work. "))
      dice_amount = int(input("Select how many dices of the given faces you want to roll: "))

      #generating dice roll number with the given input
      dice_rolls = []
      for i in range(0, dice_amount):
         dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1,dice_face))

      dice_rolls = []
      for i in range(0, dice_amount):
         dice_rolls.append(random.randint(1,dice_face))
      
      #Counting how many of each number are they and defining percentages
      num = Counter(dice_rolls)
      percentages = sum(num.values())
      total = round(percentages, 1)


      #printing final message output to the user
      print("Your dice percentages where: ")
      for face, count in num.most_common():
         print(f"{face}: {count} ({count/total:.2%})")

      
   #When the user stops wanting to play, saying them goodbye
   else:
      print("Well, it was great while it lasted! Until next time!")
      break


print("Developed by SMB Studios")
```

Comment: You should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to ask this.

Comment: Performance-related questions are fine on StackOverflow only if the question is precise about the target performance problem (ie. the problem is isolated and there are enough profiling infos). Here the main loop is doing IOs and IOs are slow (especially the one waiting for human interactions).

Comment: Note that you have your loop populating `dice_rolls` _twice_.